# Mockito instead of stubbing the method, is invoking the method

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am basically a new bee in using Mockito framework.

```
@Test
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public void testGetCaseDetailResponse() throws Exception {

    HashMap requestM = new HashMap<String, String>();
    requestM.put("transactionId", "******");
    requestM.put("clientSystem", "URW");
    requestM.put("loginId", "JUSTINN");


Mockito.when(caseDetailsService.getSAPCaseDetail(Mockito.any(), requestM))
            .thenReturn(sapCaseDetailResponse);
}
```

the below part of the code which should ideally stub the method caseDetailsService.getSAPCaseDetail **is invoking the method**. I ran on debug mode and verified that is the case.

```
Mockito.when(caseDetailsService.getSAPCaseDetail(Mockito.any(), requestM))
            .thenReturn(sapCaseDetailResponse);
```

For more info on the initialization part

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CaseDetailsServiceTest {
@Mock
RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Mock
AuthUtil authUtil;

@Mock
HttpHeaders httpHeaders;

@Mock
private HttpServletRequest httpRequest;

@Mock
SapServiceClient sapServiceClient;

@Mock
DateConvertUtils dateConvertUtils;

@Mock
CaseConverter caseConverter;

@InjectMocks
CaseDetailsService caseDetailsService;
```

I might be missing something, any help would be really appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: InjectMock does not mock the object, it creates the object with mocks. Yours mocks are anything with the annotation mock

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
Mockito.when(caseDetailsService
```

But:

```
@InjectMocks
CaseDetailsService caseDetailsService;
```

The point of `@InjectMocks` is to **insert** previously created mock objects into an instance of your **production** class under test.

In other words: `caseDetailsService` isn't a **mock**. Thus you can't use `when(caseDetailsService...)`.

You see, `when()` is used to **specify** the behavior of a Mockito created mock object. You can't apply `when()` on something that isn't a mock.

Thus, the real answer here: step back, and read a good tutorial about Mockito, and what its annotations really **mean**. Mocking frameworks are complicated, you can't learn them "trial and error"!

A good starting point: the tutorial at [vogella](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html).